# Is there a way to rollback an animation using only jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Imagine I have the following animations:

```
$("#myObject").animate({
    /* animation 1 */
}).animate({
    /* animation 2 */
}).animate({
    /* animation 3 */
});
```

I was wondering if is there a way to animate `#myObject` back on a reverse order with reverse attributes without writing it all over again.

I was thinking about making a css class and toggle it, but it won't have the animation steps. Also, css3 animations is not an option for this project.

Is it possible?

Comment: Comments are for comments, not additions to your question - there is an `Edit` button.

Comment: why don't you just write a function? pass the object and whatever values you need. 3step(object,posx1,posy1,posx2,posy2,posx3,posy3).  depending on the type of animation... you may have to write 2 functions. 1 for forward 1 for backward.

Comment: That`s what I did, but I am looking for some code optimization. If the animation gets bigger and I need to change it I will have to change it two times, reverse order, and so on. But that`s a nice start, Richard. Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I thought this was a fun question, and I wrote this: http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/hzFTg/#base

Its a very naive implementation, but it does what you are asking. So, yes there is a way to do it, but not out of the box.

Comment: Impressive! That was a very clever implementation! Congrats! :)